# Force HeavyWeight Tooltip with shaped JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, tooltip, shapes

I'm working on an application with a custom shape, and having some issue with tooltips of my buttons. I isolated the problem in a simple example, which illustrate exactly my situation.

You can see, tooltip of the middle button is well display because is larger than the root panel, but the one on the left button doesn't work and is hidden by my custom shape.

Here is my exemple :

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.Shape;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ToolTipManager;

public class ButtonDemo extends JPanel {
protected JButton b1, b2, b3;

public ButtonDemo() {
    b1 = new JButton("Disable middle button");
    b1.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);
    b1.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.LEADING);

    b2 = new JButton("Middle button");
    b2.setVerticalTextPosition(AbstractButton.BOTTOM);
    b2.setHorizontalTextPosition(AbstractButton.CENTER);

    b3 = new JButton("Enable middle button");
    b3.setEnabled(false);

    b1.setToolTipText("Click this button to disable the middle button.");
    b2.setToolTipText("This middle button does nothing when you click it. This middle button does nothing when you click it. This middle button does nothing when you click it.");
    b3.setToolTipText("Click this button to enable the middle button.");

    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("ButtonDemo");

    frame.setUndecorated(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // Create and set up the content pane.
    ButtonDemo newContentPane = new ButtonDemo();
    newContentPane.setOpaque(true); // content panes must be opaque
    frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setSize(1024, 768);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocation(0, 0);

    // Shape
    final Point[] points = new Point[]{
            //
            new Point(0, 0),
            //
            new Point(0, frame.getHeight()),
            //
            new Point(frame.getWidth() - 400, frame.getHeight()),
            //
            new Point(frame.getWidth() - 400, 25),
            //
            new Point(frame.getWidth(), 25),
            //
            new Point(frame.getWidth(), 0),
            //
            new Point(0, 0)};

    int[] xpoints = new int[points.length];
    int[] ypoints = new int[points.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        xpoints[i] = (int) points[i].getX();
        ypoints[i] = (int) points[i].getY();
    }

    Shape formeFenetre = new Polygon(xpoints, ypoints, points.length);

    frame.setShape(formeFenetre);

}
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);

    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I thought "ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);" was exactly what I was looking for, but doesn't work quite well with my JRE. By the way, I'm using Java 1.7.0_09, but should work with any JRE in 1.7.

Hope someone know what to to ! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Not sure of what the problem is. I can't see you issue using JDK 1.7.0_02 on Windows 7.

Comment: I'm currently of JDK 1.7.0_09 with windows VISTA ... tried with JDK 1.7.0_21, 1.7.0_13 ... but actually works with JDK 1.7.0_0

Comment: Niahahaha, this is killing me ... how can I have to much difference between differente JDK of different OS ... isn't java supposed to be cross-plaform ? :(.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to. Still, you can always expect some differences. This one is probably a regression. Some people will rant that Java is "Write Once Debug Everywhere".

Comment: lol, thx guillaume for your help. If any one know how I can resolve this problem, I need to make it work with most JRE... it's a main issue in my ToDo List, even rebuilding an entier TooltipManager should be an option ... if it looks smart to you. Thx again.

Comment: Its working fine on my JRE too, with version `C:\Mine\JAVA\J2SE\classes>java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"/Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)/Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)`

Comment: Doesn't work for me (java version "1.7.0_10") on Windows 7. So it looks like a version issue. I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Just a slight point, but I recommend avoiding shaped windows completely, on two grounds.  1) The programmer typically thinks they are cute or 'kewl', but the users typically don't.  2) Most seasoned developers don't really care enough to raise a bug report when they fail, and for the same reason would not spend a great deal of time trying to find workarounds.

Comment: You might need to call setLightWeightPopupEnabled(false) on the EDT.

Comment: Andrew : Totally agree, shaped window sucks for the user interface, highly recommand anyone not to use it, but in our case we need it, couldn't found an other option to smartly integrate an other application in mine.

Comment: Michael : Tryed to call it in EDT, but no change... thx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is possibly related to:

- [Bug ID: 2224554 Version 7 doesn't support translucent popup menus against a translucent window](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=2224554)
- [Bug ID: 7156657 Version 7 doesn't support translucent popup menus against a translucent window](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7156657)
- [jdk8/jdk8/jdk: changeset 5453:4acd0211f48b](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/rev/4acd0211f48b)
- [[8] Review request for 7156657 Version 7 doesn't support translucent popup menus against a translucent window](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/swing-dev/2012-June/002096.html)

Comment: Also had some issue with popup menus, but fixed them quite easily compare to the one with tooltips. Today I'll try to redevelop completely my tooltipmanager and see what I can do.